# Adding default prop for a compound component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a Modal component from a library which is written on top of ReactModal and have the following API:

```
<Modal {...props} /> // all props are passed to ReactModal
<Modal.Header />     // some styles of header are applied
<Modal.Body />       // some styles of body are applied
<Modal.Footer />     // some styles of footer
```

Now I want to set 2 props `parentSelector` and `appElement` for all Modal usages I'm doing in my application. How do I do it? I've tried creating a wrapper to add these 2 props like this

```js
function AppModal(props) {
    return (
        <Modal parentSelector={getParent} appElement={getParent()} {...props} />
    );
}
```

but this makes `AppModal.Header`, `AppModal.Body`, `AppModal.Footer` `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are actually only overwriting the Modal Component. `Modal.Header`, `Modal.Body`, and `Modal.Footer` are separate components that are set as static properties on the `Modal` class.

If you want to set the parentSelector and appElement props on all components, you should wrap all components.

```
function AppModal(props) {
  return (
    <Modal parentSelector={getParent} appElement={getParent()} {...props} />
  );
}

AppModal.Header = function (props) {
  return (
    <Modal.Header parentSelector={getParent} appElement={getParent()} {...props} />
  );
};

AppModal.Body = function (props) {
  return (
    <Modal.Body parentSelector={getParent} appElement={getParent()} {...props} />
  );
};

AppModal.Footer = function (props) {
  return (
    <Modal.Footer parentSelector={getParent} appElement={getParent()} {...props} />
  );
};
```

If they are all the same as in the example above, I would probably create a wrapping function like so:

```
function wrap (Component) {
  return function (props) {
    return <Component parentSelector={getParent} appElement={getParent()} {...props} />
  }
}

const AppModal = wrap(Modal);

AppModal.Header = wrap(Modal.Header);
AppModal.Body = wrap(Modal.Body);
AppModal.Footer = wrap(Modal.Footer);
```